# Call constructor after declaration of a class variable

Tags: c++, constructor

I have 2 classes `Point` and `Vector`.

I am reading input from a file which contains some points and I have to construct some vectors from those points.

For example, the first 3 lines of my file are the following:

```
0.0 0.0 50.0 // point a
0.0 0.0 0.0 // point b
0.0 1.0 0.0 // point c
```

I'm handling the input parsing in a different class called `Stages`, which currently looks like this:

```
class Stages{
    int fileLineNumber;
    Point eyePoint,lookPoint,upPoint;
    Vector eye,look,up;

    void parseInput(){
        // parse the 3 points here
    }

    // ....
```

Now I want to construct the vectors as `eye = point b - point a` and so on. I have written a corresponding constructor inside the `Vector` class:

```
Vector(Point p1,Point p2){
            Point diff = p2 - p1;
            x = diff.x;
            y = diff.y;
            z = diff.z;
        }
```

My question is, as I have already declared the 3 vectors inside `Stages` class, how I can call the `Vector` constructor after I have parsed the points? I can workaround either by writing a function inside the `Vector` class that sets the vector coordinates or by creating a temporary `Vector` object inside the `parseInput()` function and assigning it to the corresponding vectors. But I'm interested in using the constructor. Is it possible to use the constructor after the variable has already been declared?

Comment: No you can't. C++ does not work this way. Class members are always constructed as part of constructing the class itself. Once an instance of `Stages` is constructed, its class members are already constructed, and you can't construct them any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members are created as soon as the object is created. As such, the constructor of `Vector` has already been called on each of the three member vectors.

What you can do, assuming the vector is assignable, is construct a temporary vector, and assign it to a member:

```
eye = {a, b};
```

Comment: @YuriFeldman If you un-delete your answer, I'll upvote it. It's a fine answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a copy assignment operator:

```
Vector& operator=(const Vector&) = default;
```

The compiler generated defaulted one is enough. (C++11)
Prior to C++11, just write a simple copy assignment operator which copies every field.
Then in your client code:

```
void parseInput()
{
    // suppose pa and pb are Pointer objects, v is a member object
    v = Vector(pa, pb);
}
```

The compiler will optimize.

Comment: Even if you make some output in the copy assignment operator, the console may not display the message because it's optimized out.